# How do I find the long term behavior of a Markov chain with given eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

[image]

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Do I first find the steady state vector? If so, what's the next step. Also, what role are eigenvalues playing here?

Comment: The only eigenvalue that should matter to you in any problem about markov chains is the eigenvalue of $1$... and the normalized vectors from the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue of $1$ are precisely the steady state vectors.  You can prove that any "regular" markov chain will always have an eigenvalue of $1$, that and that regardless of initial state $x_0$ that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} A^n x_0$ will result in a normalized eigenvector.

Comment: You want to look for the normalized eigenvector corresponding the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$. This will give you a picture of the long term behavior.

Comment: what's the difference between a normalized vector and a steady state vecotr

Comment: A bit more about why eigenvalues that are different than $1$ shouldn't concern you is that if you were to suppose you had a vector $v$ with eigenvalue $\lambda \neq 1$ then $Av=\lambda v$ would not be a probability vector as the sum of the entries of $\lambda v$ would be $\lambda$ and not $1$.  By "normalized vector" I meant to say a vector with sum of entries equal to $1$.  I misspoke as it would probably be interpreted as the euclidean norm rather than the taxicab norm.

Comment: so the answer is just the steady state vector?

Comment: The eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue of $1$ such that the sum of the entries in the eigenvector is $1$ is indeed the steady state vector, yes and in the case of a regular markov chain (*one in which there exists some power of $n$ such that $A^n$ contains all strictly positive entries*) you have that *every* initial vector will tend towards that unique steady state vector.  Further, the columns of $A^n$ will all tend towards the steady state vector as well.

Comment: The normalized eigenvector you get from the corresponding eigenvalue is the steady-state vector